# login user with GET request swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, get

I have created a screen with a text field called **customer_number** text field and another screen with a text field called **password** text field. I want to integrate my app with an existing API made by the backend developers. I am new to IOS Development and I don't know how to go about it. How do I make a get request and pass the login credentials for the user to login?

I want to get the customer number from the API and pass it to the app and enable the customer to log in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is too big and complex to be replied exhaustively. You didn't tell us about the API. What kind of input does it take? What kind of response?

Supposing the simplest case. You API expects JSON objects as input and respond with another JSON object containing the information you request.

I usually do tasks like this using the `NSURLRequest`.

```
let js = ["Username":username, "Password":password]
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: .default)
let url = URL(...)
var req = URLRequest.init(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)

req.httpMethod = "POST"
// Add some header key-value pairs
req.addValue(..., forHTTPHeaderField: ...)
...
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
   guard error == nil else { return }
   guard let responseData = data else { return }
   let code = (response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode

   // Checking for code == 200 states for authorised user. Generally log-in APIs should return some 4xx code if not allowed or non-authorised user.
   if code == 200 {
      // Now we try to convert returned data as a JSON object
      do {
         let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
         // use your json object here, for example checking if contains the user number...
      } catch {
         // handle errors
      }

   } 
}
task.resume()
```

I coded this very quickly, please check the correctness of al mechanism!